# Java code to give an image sketch effect[ and other interesting/fun effects]

Tags: java, image-manipulation

I'm creating an application for which I need to convert color images to pencil sketches, for example [see this](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_Ak_YFldjZ_w/S-MRuOzCAPI/AAAAAAAAAp4/ySOKQlBzUkg/s1600/convert-photo-pencil-sketch.jpg).

answer at [Implementing Modified Sketch generation in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935955/implementing-modified-sketch-generation-in-java) gives similar effect but not quite what I want(as shown in the example above).
Can someone tell me how to get the desired sketch effect in java?

Also, are there any cookbook type resources/blogs/books/open-source-library which show the java(or any other language) code for various kind of fun looking effects to images?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In last couple of days I researched this and was able to get the desired sketch effect using java. I've [posted it](http://technotes-himanshu.blogspot.com/2011/04/how-i-wrote-javacode-to-give-pencil.html) on my blog.

Pseudocode looks like following..

```
s = Read-File-Into-Image("/path/to/image")
g = Convert-To-Gray-Scale(s)
i = Invert-Colors(g)
b = Apply-Gaussian-Blur(i)
result = Color-Dodge-Blend-Merge(b,g)
```

I found following open source code useful...

[JH Labs image filters](http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/download.html)

Processing Programming Language (**http://code.google.com/p/processing/**)(couldn't make this a hyperlink, it seems I don't have enough reputation to post more than 2 hyperlinks :) )

Answer (score 0):

The [Java Advanced Imaging](http://java.net/projects/jai/) library has some [demos](http://java.net/projects/jai-demos) which shows some basic effects on images.

Comment: thanks, I looked at it but couldn't get time to run/try the demos. It seems like good resource though.